# Find correlation between values in one column and values in other columns

Tags: r

I have a dataset that goes like this:

Species_name

| Species_name | Env_1 | Env_2 | Env_3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 0.3 | 1 | 10 |
| B | 0.1 | 4 | 11 |
| C | 0.2 | 1.5 | 9 |

And essentially I want to test wether species identity (so first column) is significantly correlated with my environmental variable (rest of the columns) to see if their their ecological niches are different.

I thought about using RDAs to do this but would need a community matrix as a response variable I think... What is the most appropriate approach?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Correlation is between numerical variables, do you mean a statistical test like ANOVA?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.